# Zend Framework + PHPUnit + Netbeans

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, phpunit

I am hardly struggling against problem I experience for last two days.
In fact I can not run test properly and receive:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Zend_Application() in
>   C:\xxxxxx\tests\application\controllers\IndexControllerTest.php on
>   line 10

IndexControllerTest is very simple and looks like this:

```
require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';


class IndexControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{

    public function setUp()
    {   
        $this->bootstrap = Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap() {
        $this->application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
        $this->application->bootstrap();
    }  
...
```

On the other hand bootstrap for tests contains only following code:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application')); //   /../application

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

Could you please help me with finding a problem? I would like to increase quality of mini project i indend to start but without testing it won't be possible.

Thank you in advance.

---

[image: structure]

I added directories structure for my project. I keep zend libs in Source Files/library/Zend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from this:

```
$this->bootstrap = Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
```

You're missing a `new` before `Zend_Application`.

But, it's not clear to me what you have the `appBootstrap` function for unless you're going to use it:

```
public function setUp()
{   
    $this->appBootstrap();
    parent::setUp();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering. Unfortunately I failed again. I modified code in the way you presented with setUp(); I got exacly the same error ("
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Application' not found in") but in appBootstrap() this time. May I ask for any addition hints as I would like to start my project with unit testing to increase quality and without enviroment it is impossible.

Comment: It means PHP is not finding the class to load. Double check if the paths to your Zend_Application is correct. The File should be under `../library/Zend/Application.php`

Comment: Hello Sam, I added picture above with directories structure. I even tried to place Zend libs in tests folder. However it did not help and I am still failing probably making some silly mistake somewhere here.

Comment: Finally i used boostrap from test defining path to it from projects properties - thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

What command are you using to run the tests?
If you don't load the bootstrap you'll get this error.
    phpunit --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php tests